# Garbage Collection for Strings

Tags: java, string, file, garbage-collection

I have a text file which I need to read line by line and do some processing on each line.

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> hm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.txt");

InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);

while(true)
{
    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    String text = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(",")).trim();
    String id = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(",") + 1).trim();
    hm.put(text,id);
}
```

I need to know, when will the strings created during the `substring()` and `trim()` operations be garbage collected?
Also, what about the String `line`?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us how you are using the map populated in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The strings themselves will be garbage collected as soon as they go out of scope, which happens at the end of each iteration of the `while` loop.  But from a memory usage point of view this is a moot point because you are storing this data into a map which will *not* go out of scope.

If you include information about how you are using this map, maybe a solution can be given which avoids having to store everything in memory.

Comment: Thanks for answering but can you explain using the variables names I have given as in which string will be garbage collected and which won't. I need to know if any strings which are not required are wasting memory leak or not.      I believe string text, id will not be garbage collected but the string line should be as well as the string created using trim() operation after each iteration. Am i correct ?

Comment: The strings aren't "leaking" memory.  They are born and then die within each iteration of the loop.  _However_, your map `hm` will continue growing possibly with each iteration of the loop.  The map is the actual "leak," if there be one.

Comment: @ak0817 You can't really create a memory leak in java because the memory is already managed, hence why there is a garbage collector in the first place.

Comment: Okay. I am getting OutOfMemory Error while running the code above even with 10 GB of heap space . The size of the file is about 2 GB(25 million lines).  That is the reason I wanted to make sure there is no sub optimal coding practice  leading to the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: So the question then is can you find some way to not store the entire file in memory?  Could you stream the file instead?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is the above code not doing it? I believed it was reading the file line by line. I apologize for my lack of knowledge in this regard. It is an existing codebase and I have very little knowledge of File I/O in java.

Comment: Do you understand that the map continues getting larger and larger with each iteration until you run out of memory?